# Does spl_autoload_register() really require that file where the class is initiated

Tags: php

I am using a `spl_autoload_register` For require apporiate classess when i intiate any class . I am wondering if it do a file require. when we intiate a class , then why i can't use class variable in required file ,

for example i have a

```
spl_autoload_register(function($class){require("views/$class.php")});
```

i have a class

```
 class home{
        function __construct(){
        $model = get_class($this).'model' ; 
         $obj = new $model ; 

 } }
```

And homemodel.php is

```
   <?php echo get_class($this) ?>
   class homemodel{}
   ?>
```

And i have another file where i intitate this class

```
    <?php
     $obj = new home ; 


      ?>
```

Now  `get_class($this)` of  homemodel.php gives error that `get_class()` is executed outside of class ., I just want to know , If the file is require when i initiate the class , so i should able to use variable of that class , But i can.t ? can someone explin why?

Comment: Is  `views/homemodel.php` the correct path for `homemodel.php`? I would  guess you have a relative path problem if it is.

Comment: I just can't able to write what i am asking? Sorry ..   But i am imagining like where we intiate a class , spl_autoload_register Do this `require(file that is defined in spl function');` Then it initiate the class @bassxzero

Comment: http://www.php-fig.org/psr/psr-4/ this page has a example implementation using the currect PSR4 autoloading standard. This requires that you use namespaces, which I would suggest anyway.